# How to improve speed of DNS lookups

Tags: domain-name-system

I am new to configuring DNS servers. I have a situation where I'm setting up DNS services on a firewalled network on Solaris 5.11 machines. The old DNS setup was using Windows DNS services and I'd like to move it to using DNS services on Solaris.

The problem is when using my DNS server set up and attempting to run an application that contacts a database outside of the firewall the application connects but is like 5 times slower than the old DNS server implementation.

The only thing I can see is that the old implementation fails quickly or at least quicker than my DNS server. The strange thing is that the server name where the database is stored (let's call it dbserver) does not resolve if it use the new DNS servers on Solaris nor does it resolve from the old DNS servers! But it fails a hell of a lot quicker with the old DNS server.

```
$ time nslookup dbserver olddns
Server:         olddns
Address:        10.100.0.10#53

** server can't find dbserver: SERVFAIL


real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.006s
$ time nslookup dbserver newdns
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
Server:         newdns
Address:        10.100.13.21#53

** server can't find dbserver: SERVFAIL


real    0m10.017s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.006s
$
```

Essentially I think I merely need to figure out how to have my new DNS server fail quicker or at least realize quicker that it doesn't know what this machine name resolves to. How can I do that?

I am not sure why this is on hold but I'll try to be explicit - Desired end result: to have a DNS server that is as fast as the old DNS server. The specific problem is that the new server is a lot slower. I think I explained the environment. As for the specific configuration I'm not sure what to post so I figured that people would ask for the config files they needed. I will include my `/etc/named.conf` file. Please let me know if you need more. As for attempted solutions I do not know what to try.

```
$ cat /etc/named.conf
options {
  directory       "/etc/namedb/working";
  pid-file        "/var/run/named/pid";
  dump-file       "/var/dump/named_dump.db";
  statistics-file "/var/stats/named.stats";
};

zone "ourdomain.example" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/namedb/master/rde.db";
};

zone "13.100.10.in-addr-arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/namedb/master/13.100.10.db";
};

zone "14.100.10.in-addr-arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/namedb/master/14.100.10.db";
};
```

BIND 9.10.5-P3

I ran /usr/sbin/named with -g and when I did my nslookup I saw:

```
01-Aug-2018 16:52:34.755 network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:1::53#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:34.757 network unreachable resolving '_nfsv4idmapdomain/TXT/IN': 2001:500:1::53#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:34.758 network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:34.759 network unreachable resolving '_nfsv4idmapdomain/TXT/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:34.761 network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:34.763 network unreachable resolving '_nfsv4idmapdomain/TXT/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:39.590 network unreachable resolving 'oradev01/A/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
01-Aug-2018 16:52:39.591 network unreachable resolving 'oradev01/A/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
```

Comment: Can you include configuration information for the server and the computer you are testing from, including info on how the computer you are testing from attempts to resolve names?  Most interesting to me is the first line of your nslookup request to newserver.  It seems like that first line could represent the extra 10 seconds.

Comment: If your Solaris DNS server software is ISC BIND, you may have overlooked the fourth step in its DNS resolution order: 1.) if the server is authoritative for the domain (=master or slave), answer based on that info, 2.) if the asked information is in cache and not stale, use it, 3.) if a forwarder is configured, use it, **4.) recursively query public nameservers, starting with the global DNS root servers.** If your DNS server has no connectivity to public DNS root servers, you'll want to specify `options { forward only; };` to avoid wasting time attempting to reach them.

Comment: 127.0.0.1? Check the `/etc/hosts` file on the machine from which you ran that DNS query.

Comment: Not sure what to check for but I have entries for 127.0.0.1 as well as a few other machines like the NIS master and slave, a license server and a backup server.

Comment: @telcoM It is recommended that a given DNS server is not both authoritative and recursive at the same time

Comment: Which bind version it is? Did you increase logging to see what happening? Did you try doing `dig` queries directly from the DNS server itself to rule out network transmission?

Comment: Comments are limited in length so I added to the original question.

Comment: Bump... Bump... Bump... Bump... Bump...

Comment: How do you want to connect to the database server if the DNS query for "dbserver" fails? How do you expect the resolution to work then? Why not just add an entry to your DNS server ?

Comment: Connection to a machine does not require DNS. DNS is for translation of machine names to IP addresses and it's not the only mechanism. There's also /etc/hosts and the NIS hosts map. If the machine appears in either of those then connection is possible. However these two additional methods do not scale as well. I have fixed my problem by putting in a hint for "." to point to an empty named.ca file. Not sure why that worked.